# how to adjust row height of pandas dataframe in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the problem of limiting the row height of the panda's data frame.

[image: here is my view]

The Chinese character sometimes simply align as a vertical line, which messes up the view.

I didn't see any row height options in 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html

Could  anyone suggest a way to fix the view?

Comment: could you please provide a small example to make it easier to experiment?

Comment: Is the Screenshot supposed to look that way? cant really make out anything